What is the 'P=NP?' building?
I remember that I read somewhere some years ago that they've built a computing building with the 'P=NP?' question built in it from bricks so that they later have the option to rearrange these bricks to form $P \neq NP$ or $P=NP$. Now I cannot find anything about this at all. What is this building?
ChatGPT thinks it is the Gates Computer Science Building at Stanford University, but I couldn't verify this in any way.
ps. Cross-posted from https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/167665 where I didn't get any answers.

https://www.cs.princeton.edu/general/bricks

I'm happy to accept this if you convert it to an answer.

The building in question is the Princeton CS building: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/general/bricks
Here is a photo of the bricks:

